# How to click an image and be redirected to a new site C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, backend, imagesource

I have a facebook button on my site using C# and I want to be able to click on the image and have it redirect the user to my facebook page. How would I get this done?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve], and update your question.

Comment: Add an event handler for the onclick event of your image, then set the window.location.href to your facebook page url.

Comment: No offence, but this has nothing to do with ASP.NET, images or C#. It's purely HTML and pretty basic HTML at that. May I suggest you run through some tutorials first?

Comment: Learn about hyperlinks.

Comment: `<a href="facebook-link-here"><img/></a>`

Comment: You will want to wrap your image with an `<a href="insertlinkhere"> ... </a>` so that the image functions as a link. Unless of course you have a more complex setup, in which case you will need to describe in greater detail what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should set image in (a) tag and write facebook page link in the href property:-

```
<a href="facebook.com/..." >
    <image src="..."/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic html**:

```
<a href="url-link">
   <img src="bla.png">
</a>
```

**Or with jQuery**:

```
<img id="image1" src="image1.png">
<script>
    $('#image1').click(function(){
    window.location.href="url-link";
     });
</script>
```

Comment: That's too complicated for the task at hand. KiSS

Comment: Why jQuery?! That's just madness